# String Formatting & NullPointerException's

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Whenever I **don't** give a value to one of my phone numbers (null) and print it to the screen with this current code block, it gives me a NullPointerException. I don't want to have to fill **every** spot in my 'phone book' with contacts before reading them because it would just be **way** too much to type.

This is the code where the exception is being thrown:

```
for (int i = 0; i< array1.length; i++) {
  num++;
  System.err.println("Contact: " + num);
  System.out.print(array1[counterB2][counterB]);
  counterB++;

  System.out.print(" " + array1[counterB2][counterB]);
  counterB++;

  String[] phoneNumArr= { 
    array1[counterB2][2].substring(0, 3),
    array1[counterB2][2].substring(3,6),
    array1[counterB2][2].substring(6)};


  System.out.println(" ");
  if (!array1[counterB2][2].equals(null)) {
    System.out.println(phoneMsgFmt.format(phoneNumArr));
    counterB = 0;
    counterB2++;
  }
}
```

Any help improving this so that it would work properly would be appreciated.

Here's the rest of the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.awt.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
public class testMattWalker {
  //
  public static void main (String[] args){

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner input3 = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner input4 = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner input5 = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner input6 = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner input7 = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner input8 = new Scanner(System.in);

    int counter = 0;
    int counter2 = 0;

    int counterB = 0;
    int counterB2 = 0;

    int counterC = 0;

    int counterD = 0;

    int counterE = 0;

    String yn = "";

    String searchLast = "";
    String searchFirst = "";
    String searchNumber = "";

    int maxNumberOfPeople = 5;

    boolean go = true;

    DecimalFormat phoneDecimalFmt = new DecimalFormat("0000000000");
    java.text.MessageFormat phoneMsgFmt=new java.text.MessageFormat("({0})-{1}-{2}");

    //Temp VAriables for entry 
    String firstNameOfEntry = "";
    String lastNameOfEntry = "";
    String personPhoneNumber = "";
    //

    //create array
    String [][] array1 = new String[5][3];

    while (go = true) {

      String choice = "";

      System.err.println("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nDIDGITAL PHONE BOOK 2013");   
      System.out.println("1- Create phone book\n2- Display phone book\n3- Find person(s) by last name\n4- Find person(s) by first name\n5- Find person(s) by phone number\n6- Exit application");
      choice = input.nextLine(); 

      if (choice.equals("1") && counter2 != maxNumberOfPeople) {
        System.err.println("\n\n\n\n\nPHONE BOOK ENTRY CREATOR:");
        System.out.println("Please enter the first name of the person you wish to enter: ");
        array1[counter2][counter] = input2.nextLine();
        counter++;

        System.out.println("Please enter the last name of the person you wish to enter: ");
        array1[counter2][counter] = input3.nextLine();
        counter++;

        System.out.println("Please enter the phone number of this person: example:9057773344");
        array1[counter2][counter] = input4.nextLine();
        counter = 0;
        counter2++;

      }else if (choice.equals("2")) {
        int num = 0;

        System.out.println("SEE I CAN FORMAT NUMBERS... I just didn't have time to put it on every one.");

        for (int i = 0; i< array1.length; i++) {
          num++;
          System.err.println("Contact: " + num);
          System.out.print(array1[counterB2][counterB]);
          counterB++;

          System.out.print(" " + array1[counterB2][counterB]);
          counterB++;

          String[] phoneNumArr= { 
            array1[counterB2][2].substring(0, 3),
            array1[counterB2][2].substring(3,6),
            array1[counterB2][2].substring(6)};


          System.out.println(" ");
          if (!array1[counterB2][2].equals(null)) {
            System.out.println(phoneMsgFmt.format(phoneNumArr));
            counterB = 0;
            counterB2++;
          }
        }

      }else if (choice.equals("3")) {
        System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n\nPlease enter the last name of the person you are searching for: ");
        searchLast = input6.nextLine();
        counterC = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
          if (searchLast.equals(array1[counterC][1])) {
            System.out.println(array1[counterC][0] + " " + array1[counterC][1] + " " + array1[counterC][2]);
          }
          counterC++;
        }
      }else if (choice.equals("4")) {
        System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n\nPlease enter the first name of the person you are searching for: ");
        searchFirst = input7.nextLine();
        counterD = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
          if (searchFirst.equals(array1[counterD][0])) {
            System.out.println(array1[counterC][0] + " " + array1[counterC][1] + " " + array1[counterC][2]);
          }
          counterD++;
        }
      }else if (choice.equals("5")) {
        System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n\nPlease enter the phone number of the person you are searching for: ");
        searchNumber = input8.nextLine();
        counterE = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
          if (searchNumber.equals(array1[counterE][2])) {
            System.out.println(array1[counterC][0] + " " + array1[counterC][1] + " " + array1[counterC][2]);
          }
          counterE++;
        }         
      }else if (choice.equals("6")) {
        System.err.println("Are you sure? [y/n]");
        yn = input5.nextLine();
        if (yn.equals("y")) {
          System.err.println("CLOSING...");
          System.exit(0);
        }else if (yn.equals("n")){ 
          System.out.println("Resuming...");
        }else {System.err.println("ERROR"); System.exit(0);}
      }
    }
  }// end of main
}// end of class
```

**EDIT:** What I've been trying to do is create a way to only display the phone number if the element in the array is not empty but It just doesn't seem to want to work for me ;--;

Comment: Please improve your variable naming. counter, counter2, counterB, counterB2, counterC, counterD, counterE, input, input2,... input8 (btw  where is input1?) and best of all: array1. Also if you want a infinite loop: just use `while(true)` but don't use an assignment there! Even `while(go = false)` will be a infinite loop!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting a `NullPointerException` probably because you're referencing a method of (`String`) `array1[counterB2][2]` **before** checking that value for `null` here: `if (!array1[counterB2][2].equals(null))`.

This happens when you initialize `phoneNumArr`, which contains calls to `substring` on `array1[counterB2][2]`.

If `array1[counterB2][2]` is `null`, calling `substring` on it will throw the `NullPointerException`.

Just enclose your `substring` statements within the check for `null` and you should be all right.

Finally, **dont't** use `if (!array1[counterB2][2].equals(null))`, use `if (array1[counterB2][2] != null)`.

Otherwise, you might end up calling `Object.equals` on a `null` `Object`, which again, will throw `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Yeah it only fixes one exception. Since I have 5 contacts (I know a lot right?) If I fill only one out it will work for the first contact, then what you said keeps the NullPointerException away for the second contact but when it goes to do the third (which is null) it throws it again.

Comment: Got it, it was just another null pointer caused by the counter only resetting when there had been a number entered.

Answer (score 1):

Just check whenever you do nextLine() if the User really entered something via

```
 if(string != null)...
```

check

Answer (score 1):

Comparing the strings using '.equals(null)' will throw a NullPointerException if the first object is null. Instead, compare using:

```
string == null
```

or obviously

```
string != null
```

for what you want to do.

You are right to prefer the .equals() method for String comparison but not when you're checking if something is null.

I also noticed that the condition for your while loop won't work as expected, you are assigning 'true' to the 'go' boolean every time when you use '(go = true)'. Instead, either use:

```
while (go == true)
```

or simply

```
while (go)
```

Comment: Yeah I usually do the 'while (go)' but I was just messing around trying to fix my problem and probably entered it accidentally. Thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 0):

you shoudl employ null check before working with Strings here. Thats the standard way to do these.